# Magento - only show special price

Tags: magento

I have a problem with the special price in grid mode product view.
I want the special prices to show the way the sold out items show, with a little image saying SALE, but without the normal prices showing.
http://www.tigerandelephant.com/index.php/t-shirts-1.html heres the link to the product page.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Here is the answer to your question: http://www.pauldonnellydesigns.com/blog/magento-display-sale-icon-if-special-price/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking getSpecialPrice on the product model? If it returns an empty don't apply your image and show the normal prices, if it has a value apply your special class/image to get the sale ribbon and don't show the normal prices.

Comment: Hi Darren thanks for answering!
I tried implementing the special price, so the sale ribbon only shows when there is a special price and doesn't if its a normal price. I managed doing that but i couldn't find the code that **only** calls the special price, without calling all the normal prices. Can you tell me which code I am looking for to just call special price on special priced products?

Comment: Hi you are going to want to edit a file in your theme called price.phtml. You will find this under template/catalog/product. This has all the views for different pricing combinations.